# Modifying the block placement strategy of HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I would like to modify the default block placement strategy of HDFS to suit my application.
 For example, I have two files say file1(128MB) and file2(128MB). Having the block size as 64MB, each of the files would be split into two blocks.

I want to make sure that block1 of both file1 and file2 are placed on the same datanode. If possible i would also like to make sure that the replicas are also placed on the same set of datanodes.

Question 1.
Is this possible? If so, Which classes in the source code need to be modified?
Question 2.
How are commands such as *copyFromLocal* mapped to functions in the hadoop source code?

Answer (score 4):

The default behaviour of the block placement policy can be modified by extending the [BlockPlacementPolicy](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/hdfs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/BlockPlacementPolicy.html) interface and pointing the class to the **dfs.block.replicator.classname** property in the Hadoop configuration files.

Hadoop operations are not tied to a particular node, this makes the Hadoop more resilient to the inherent problems in distributed computing. What is the requirement for having blocks for two files on a particular node? With the requirement known a better solution can be found.

Comment: We intend to use hadoop for log processing. The requirement is that we want all the records related to a single user should be located on the same set of datanodes. If this can be achieved it will remove the need for data migration when a user's session needs to be retreived using a map-reduce job.