# Storing HDFS data only on specific nodes in a Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, data-storage

We have a 30 nodes production cluster. We want to add 5 data nodes for additional storage to handle the interim spike of data( around 2 TB). This data is to be stored temporarily and we want to get rid of it after 15 days.

**Is it possible to make sure that the interim data (2 TB) coming in will be stored only on the newly added data nodes?**

*I am looking for something similar to YARN node labelling.*

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whats your HDP / Hadoop version?

Comment: @mazaneicha : Its HDP 2.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know a simple way to achieve this in the same HDFS cluster.
But I think you can achieve this behavior by implementing a custom "Block Placement Policy".
However, performing this task can be somewhat risky and complex.

Here is the HDFS jira ticket where this functionality is defined/added that allows you to customize this policy ([JIRA TICKET](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-385)).

You can read here the current behavior of choosing datanode to understand you better if you want to customize it:
[link 1](https://ofirm.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/exploring-hdfs-block-placement-policy/)

Also here you can find a post with several references that can be useful on how to implement a custom policy and the risks of it: 
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992858/can-i-have-different-block-placement-policies-in-hdfs)

Other readings that I recommend if you want to take this way:

[link 2](https://hadoopblog.blogspot.com/2009/09/hdfs-block-replica-placement-in-your.html)

[post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494179/modifying-the-block-placement-strategy-of-hdfs)

This is a good paper about an experiment with a custom block placement policy to place replicas in SSD or HDD (Hybrid cluster):
[paper](https://peerj.com/preprints/1320v1.pdf)

I think that if possible, it will be simpler to use a second cluster. E.g. you can eval ViewFS that uses namespaces to reference each cluster:

[viewFs reference](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/ViewFs.html)

[link 3](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/data-storage/content/using_viewfs_to_manage_multiple_namespaces.html)

Regards,